# Optocoupler H22A2 driving a PLC input

Tags: opto-isolator, plc

See [*Optocouplers and Solid-State Relays: Application Examples*](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83741/83741.pdf), example 2.

I have existing [H22A2](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/H22A1,2,3.pdf) optocouplers that I am trying to run 12 VDC through to get a PLC input to turn on and off. I am using a 1 kΩ resistor on the 5 VDC LED. I am using a 2.7 kΩ resistor on the optotransistor side with the 12 VDC.

I can get the input to turn on and off, but the voltage drop is so minimal that it is way to sensitive to be consistent. Any ideas?

PLC model from Automation Direct [BX-DM1E-18ED13](https://cdn.automationdirect.com/static/specs/bxdm1e_18ed13.pdf)

I will have 4 of the optos going to 4 separate inputs.

> 9.0 VDC ON  <2.0 VDC OFF for inputs

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxzu8r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. (1) There is a schematic editor built in to the editor toolbar. Post a schematic of your actual circuit. (2) What do you mean by "emitter"? This usually refers to the transistor pin with the arrow on it. If you are referring to the LED you will cause a lot of confusion. (3) You should also embed the Example 2 image in your post so we all don't have to follow links. (4) Finally, add the make and model of your PLC and a link to the datasheet.

Comment: Sorry, first post.

Comment: Hi, @Kurt. A month later and you are still having trouble with this. You do not need to use a pull-up. Did you wire as shown in Figure 5 of my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unclear but I suspect that you think that the PLC requires a pull-up or pull-down resistor as shown in the Example 2 of your link. This is not the case.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbJLSC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1.*

The PLC input can be connected directly to ground in the case of a current-sourcing type or directly to positive supply in the case of a current-sinking type. Typically about 10 mA will flow and ensure adequate illumination of the internal opto-coupler which isolates the inputs from the internal logic.

For your circuit you wire the opto-isolator's transistor as shown depending on input type.

The current-sinking type of input is often called a PNP input as it would work with PNP-type three-wire industrial sensors. Since you are using a "two-wire" opto-transistor the NPN transistor works in both configurations.

---

Update after links posted.

[image]

*Figure 2. The PLC accepts sinking, sourcing or AC configuration.*

That means that there are back-to-back diodes or a rectifier on the inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5P3tU.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Options for interfacing your opto-switch.*

Choose (a) or (b) to suit other switches in the system.

---

Update 2:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7tKAG.png)</sup>

*Figure 4. Redrawn OP's schematic.*

Corrected version of your schematic is above. Note that this is the same as I drew in Figure 3b.

[image]

*Figure 5. Correct schematic with current path highlighted.*

Comment: BRX plc from automationdirect. Model BX-DM1E-18ED13. I have a 5vdc power supply going through a 1k resistor to the LED. The optotransistor side I have 12vdc in order to be able to turn ON the input. (10-24vdc required).

Comment: You're asking too much of those you hope will help you. Please post a *link to the datasheet* for the device in question - not the catalog page.

Comment: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/H22A1,2,3.pdf

Comment: I think I am not driving the LED bright enough. I did get it to work with a multimeter. Able to pull 12v down to almost zero before blowing the LED.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help further until you address the points I numbered in my comment under your question. I was looking for the datasheet for the PLC. Put all the required information **in your question** - not scattered through the comments.

Comment: Need any other info?

Comment: The schematic in your question does not show the power connections to your input module. Do you understand Figures 2 and 3 in my answer?

Comment: The plc is sinking input

Comment: (1) No it's not. It can be wired as sourcing or sinking as explained in my answer. I presume you are saying that you have wired it as sinking. (2) You still haven't shown the power connections to your input module. (3) You didn't answer whether you understand Figures 2 and 3 in my answer. Why?

Comment: The plc is wired as sinking input. I understand your figures 2 and 3. It is example (a) "Current-sourcing" input mode. I updated the schematic.

Comment: Your power supplies aren't drawn correctly. You have four where you should have two, the polarities are wrong and you have no return path. They are open circuits. Can you correct the schematic?

Comment: Schematic updated. I did not understand the power supply symbols at first.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: So I do not need a resistor on the 12vdc side?

Comment: No external resistor is required. The opto-transistor behaves like a switch.

Comment: I tried removing the resistor, but then my input never shuts off.

Comment: What is controlling the opto-coupler LED? Is it turning off properly? Put a visible LED in series with it so you can monitor.